# Unable to Patch SUPEE 5344 on v 1.12.0.2

Tags: supee-6788, supee-7405, ee-1.12.0.2

I have a website using Magento v1.12.0.2 and it does not have shoplift patched yet. I want to apply the patch SUPEE-5344 but I'm unable to patch it successfully.

Without SUPEE-5344, patches SUPEE-6788 and SUPEE-7405 are not being recognized by the Magento checker service.

Have any of you guys faced similar problem in past and provide and helpful info?

Comment: Failed patch applications spit out a log of where they are running into issues. Post that, otherwise it's all guessing as to what's wrong. And no Magento store with the shoplift bug should be left publicly accessible for your customer's sakes.

Comment: The rejection log or .rej files are not getting generated. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had got the exact same issue almost a year ago. I followed following steps:

1. Make sure Compiler is disabled
2. Make sure Cache is disabled
3. Go to the file **applied.patches.list** in **app/etc folder** and check the last successful applied patch
4. Refer the [Magento Archive of patches](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/patch-releases-2015.html) and [patch list](https://magento.com/security/patches) , sequence of patches, match it with **applied.patches.list** file and make sure no patch is missing upto **SUPEE-5344**
5. Download all the patches after **SUPEE-5344** from the site
6. Upload all the downloaded Patches in your Magento Root
7. Now you have to run each patch in sequence as given in the Archive, make sure you dont skip any patch. Run it through a Php script so you can see if there is any error while patching.

create a patch.php (or any name you want to give) in root of your magento, with the following code:

```
           <?php
             print("<PRE>");   
             passthru("/bin/bash YOUR_FULL_PATCH_NAME.sh");
             print("</PRE>");
          ?>
```

Replace "YOUR_FULL_PATH_NAME" with the patch name. 
Notes:

> 1. Run the script for each Patch in the sequence by replacing the YOUR_FULL_PATH_NAME
> 2. In case an error occurs while running the Patch, revert it back by replacing the code with:
>
>    passthru("/bin/bash YOUR_PATCH_NAME.sh -R");

Comment: welcome Parekh, hope you solved the issue.

Comment: The problem was someone modified few core files and it broke patch 7405 v1.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Enterprise sometimes runs different patch versions than Magento community. For example, SUPEE-5344 is not available for your Magento version. I'm also not completely sure which checker service you are using, but they mainly focus on Magento Community and there is a possibility that a patch cannot be detected for various reasons. If the status response is "unknown" you should verify another way. If the status says "vulnerable" there is a big chance you still need to apply the patch. Refer to this quote from the Magento patch page:

> If you are on Magento Enterprise Edition 1.12.0.2 and lower, then please apply SUPEE-1533 and the appropriate patch for your version:

https://magento.com/security-patch

You can download patches for Enterprise within your Magento account under a downloads tab. Verify that you have all those patches corresponding to your Magento version installed. I don't have access to this, but this repository has a nice list as a reference. Do download them from your account though to make sure you get the right ones. https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/tree/master/EE1.12

**Installed patches**

Applied patches are logged in an `applied.patches.list` file in the app/etc folder. The installed patches should be listed there. To be absolutely certain a patches is installed you could verify it manually. In the patch file itself there are lines indicating which file is being patched. The "+"'s and "-"'s indicate what lines of code are to be removed or added. Verify that the "-" lines are gone and the "+" lines are added. If your still in doubt, it's a good idea to get a certified Magento developer to take a look at it.